# Allocating an elastic IP using AWS SDK tools for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) and I noticed that when I stop-start a server the elastic IP is de-associated from the instance. In my program I know what the elastic IP is but how can I re-associate it from the tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a .NET programmer so I can't write you example code.
You can use the [AssociateAddressRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_EC2_Model_AssociateAddressRequest.htm) class which resides in the [Amazon.EC2.Model](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_EC2_Model.htm) namespace

This would look like this

```
String instanceId = "your instance id";
String publicIp = "your public ip";

ec2.associateAddress(new AssociateAddressRequest()
            .withInstanceId(instanceId)
            .withPublicIp(publicIp));
```

Found an example usage [here](http://code.google.com/p/xe-tools/source/browse/trunk/xe-instant/aws/AwsConsoleApp.java?r=92): method `process_assign_address_command` line 593

**EDIT:**

Offtopic, but still might interest you: this is how I found the code example.
http://code.google.com/intl/en/query/#q=AssociateAddressRequest

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. While that wasn't .NET it was enough to get me there! :D

Comment: Oh yeah just realized why this looked so familiar.. Sample is Java

Comment: Hehe well it's not so bad in .NET just different syntax really!

Answer (score 0):

```
 AmazonEC2Client amazonEc2client = GetAmazonClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AwsRegionEndPint"]);   
 var associateRequest = new AssociateAddressRequest
              {
                  PublicIp = Your Elastic Ip,
                  InstanceId = Your InstanceId
              };
              amazonEc2client.AssociateAddress(associateRequest);
```