# public ip address creation using aws sdk for .net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the AWS SDK for .NET. How can I create a public IP address to be associated to an instance i just started/created?

I have got this solution to link

[Allocating an elastic IP using AWS SDK tools for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973674/allocating-an-elastic-ip-using-aws-sdk-tools-for-net)

but this has the criteria that you know the Public IP Address, In case The public IP addresss is not known , how can i create the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the EC2 documentation regarding [instance IP addressing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html). The documentation mentions several cases when your instance will already have a public IP.

Comment: @PavelSafronov In case of a persistent IP, an elastic IP needs to be created and associated. How can i create an elastic IP programmatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EC2 - then the instance you're creating has public IP.
Just use DescribesInstances to extract this info.

If you are using VPC, then assuming this instance is launched on a public subnet-  the only missing part is to allocate an elastic IP and connect it with the instance.

Also possible is to place this instance behind ELB and then you'll probably only need the ELB public address (or actually the DNS name) which was created before and is already known.

Comment: In case of a persistent IP, an elastic IP needs to be created and associated. How can i create an elastic IP programmatically. Thanks